# Is there a Pandas function equivalent to Stata fillin?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, stata

Stata's `fillin` command makes a dataset rectangular. How can I do the same in Pandas?

I have tried to simulate the `fillin` command in this way, but it is very slow and expensive:

```
from itertools import product

collapse_df = collapse_df[['cod', 'loc_id', 'fob']]
var = list(product(collapse_df['loc_id'], collapse_df['cod']))
var = list(set([i for i in var]))
var_df = collapse_df[0:0]
for idx,item in enumerate(var):
    df_t = collapse_df[(collapse_df['loc_id'] == item[0]) & (collapse_df['cod'] == item[1])]
    if (len(df_t) == 0):
        df_t.loc[0, 'loc_id'] = item[0]
        df_t.loc[0, 'cod'] = item[1]
    var_df = pd.concat([var_df, df_t], axis=0)
collapse_df = var_df.drop_duplicates()
```

**Edit:**

input:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1giWlKXNFaXeLpaVSUDc04AwyogD-ASJK/view?usp=sharing

output:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UcADbQnbDELGPHZVIt2BmCYYTzU5pZtf/view?usp=sharing

Resource: https://www.stata.com/manuals13/dfillin.pdf

Comment: `collapse_df` is currently undefined. Can you provide some sample import and output?

Comment: kindly provide a reproducible dataframe, with expected output

Comment: [pyjanitor](https://github.com/pyjanitor-devs/pyjanitor) has [complete](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.complete.html) which is similar to fillin. If you're not looking to add an additional dependency you can always check the source code and replicate how they approach the problem (https://github.com/pyjanitor-devs/pyjanitor/blob/bfea08b05d7c8f94c7f50f031c79bf7992a40108/janitor/utils.py#L737)

Comment: yea, depending on your use case, you can use asfreq, resample, reindex, `complete` just abstracts the process ... Also, your input, output example is not helpful/useful/ clear enough to work with

Comment: Can you instead just fillin the first 5 rows. Make the sample input end at `106     17  1.350000e+04` and show the output for just those 5 rows?

Comment: @HenryEcker I've updated the example. Please review it, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% certain what your desired result is from the input that you've provided. However, I took a stab at solving this going off what the Stata docs state.

Set up test data (very important when asking a question, please provide in the future)

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import itertools

np.random.seed(42)
test_data = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'AgeGroup': np.random.choice(['20-24', '18-19', '10-17'], size=10, p=[0.75, 0.20, 0.05]),
        'Sex': np.random.choice(['male', 'female'], size=10),
        'Race': np.random.choice(['black', 'white'], size=10, p=[0.3, 0.7]),
        'x1': np.random.uniform(size=10),
        'x2': np.random.normal(0, 1, size=10)
    }
)

test_data
```

Out:

```
  AgeGroup     Sex   Race        x1        x2
0    20-24  female  black  0.785176 -0.600254
1    10-17    male  white  0.199674  0.947440
2    20-24  female  white  0.514234  0.291034
3    20-24  female  white  0.592415 -0.635560
4    20-24  female  black  0.046450 -1.021552
5    20-24  female  white  0.607545 -0.161755
6    20-24  female  black  0.170524 -0.533649
7    18-19  female  black  0.065052 -0.005528
8    20-24  female  white  0.948886 -0.229450
9    20-24  female  white  0.965632  0.389349
```

My approach is basically:

1. Find all possible combinations of identity columns
2. Find which combinations do not exist in the provided dataset
3. Create an empty dataset with the missing combinations and concatenate it to the existing dataset

```
def fill_in(df, id_cols):
    """Fill in empty records for combinations of id_cols that do not exist
    in dataset.
    
    Args:
        df: dataset
        id_cols: list of identity columns

    Returns:
        filled_df: dataframe with empty records for missing combinations of id_cols
    """
    # create all possible unique combinations of id_cols
    # and find combos that do not exist in the dataset
    id_combos = list(itertools.product(*[df[c].unique() for c in id_cols]))
    existing_combos = df[id_cols].apply(tuple, axis=1).unique()
    missing_combos = set(id_combos) - set(existing_combos)

    # create an empty dataframe with the missing combos
    other_cols = [c for c in df.columns if c not in id_cols]
    new_idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(missing_combos, names=id_cols)
    empty_data = np.empty(shape=(len(missing_combos), len(other_cols))).fill(np.nan)
    filled_df = pd.DataFrame(data=empty_data, index=new_idx, columns=other_cols).reset_index()

    # concat dataset with empty dataset for missing combos
    return pd.concat([df.assign(_fill_in=0), filled_df.assign(_fill_in=1)])
```

Trying it out:

```
fill_df(test_data, ['AgeGroup', 'Sex', 'Race'])
```

Results:

```
  AgeGroup     Sex   Race        x1        x2  _fill_in
0    20-24  female  black  0.785176 -0.600254         0
1    10-17    male  white  0.199674  0.947440         0
2    20-24  female  white  0.514234  0.291034         0
3    20-24  female  white  0.592415 -0.635560         0
4    20-24  female  black  0.046450 -1.021552         0
5    20-24  female  white  0.607545 -0.161755         0
6    20-24  female  black  0.170524 -0.533649         0
7    18-19  female  black  0.065052 -0.005528         0
8    20-24  female  white  0.948886 -0.229450         0
9    20-24  female  white  0.965632  0.389349         0
0    10-17  female  white       NaN       NaN         1
1    10-17  female  black       NaN       NaN         1
2    18-19    male  black       NaN       NaN         1
3    10-17    male  black       NaN       NaN         1
4    18-19    male  white       NaN       NaN         1
5    18-19  female  white       NaN       NaN         1
6    20-24    male  white       NaN       NaN         1
7    20-24    male  black       NaN       NaN         1
```